# How to Unpause a Linux 7 server

Tags: oracle-linux

I have an oracle Linux 7 server as VM in vmware vsphere. I accedently clicked on the PAUSE button located at the top right corner of the main screen. It paused all CPU functionalities and got a black screen that not responding to any Keyboard key! How do I recover that?

Comment: Is there a play button to press, or a "VM" menu with a "Pause" selection that you can uncheck.  I'm not a vSphere user, so I'm only going by what [the documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-CFE06F56-8AF4-4FFF-92B7-675EBA7DEE63.html) says.